# What is the problem with this mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
select count (*) from sales_order where date_format
(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') >= 
'2009-11-02' and date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d')
 <= '2010-12-08' and customer_id in 
(14,1113,1115,1117,1132,1312,1345);
```

it gave me this error

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
 manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near '*) from sales_order where 
date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2009-11-02' and' at line 1
```

Please let me know where is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No space allow for `count (*)`

```
count(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the space after COUNT. Do not use a space here. See this MySQL bug: [Bug #2664 An extra space after Count in a Count(distinct... statement fails](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2664)